# how to determine that on the Activity opened fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am use scandit library. It is activity. On the this activity i call fragment. When i call fragment, i am stop camera. It work. But i have some problem. If i call fragment, camera has stop. good. then if my phone goes into sleep mode call onPause() method. Then if i turn phone, call onStart() method. in  onStart() i call start camera. I want if activity has fragment and call onStart() camera not start.

```
public class ScanActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ScanditSDKListener {
```

.....

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // When the activity is in the background immediately stop the
        // scanning to save resources and free the camera.
        stopScan();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // Once the activity is in the foreground again, restart scanning.
        **Then I want to check if the fragment is open, do not include**
        startScan();
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Fragment Manager. When you start the fragment give it a tag and get the fragment instance from its tag.

Another crude way can be setting a static boolean flag and making it true in on resume and false on stop. I would go with the getfragmentbyTag("fragment-one") method.

**Edit**

Actually go with first method only. Ignore the second. Not only static variables are bad but if activity stays out of focus for a long time or goes into backstack, GC will decide to clean up your static variables. All in all it was a bad suggestion and I take it back.

**Edit**

Here is the code:

When starting a fragment, assign it a tag:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction;
 transaction = ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment,"MyFrag");
 transaction.addToBackStack("a");
 transaction.commit();
 getActivity().getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Look up the fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
android.app.Fragment tempFragment=fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MyFrag");
```

In essence, you replaced a new fragment, you assigned it a tag and used that tag to get current object of the same Fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // Once the activity is in the foreground again, restart scanning.

    **Then I want to check if the fragment is open, do not include**
    if(tempFragment!=null)
   {
    //Fragment is open so do not include your code

    }
  else
   {
     Fragment is null
    startScan();
   }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: it does not work. I have a few fragments. first works. then the second call. and fails